# Edit View - Droplist select option - dislaying the current value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a edit view - my question is on the code below how would I have the selected value show the current value in the database? Example let's say the value of PaymentStatus is Weekly. I want the list to show Weekly, not Annually. I guess somehow dynamically change he selected option.

Thanks,
EB

Cotroller:

```
List<SelectListItem> Payment = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Annually", Value = "Annually" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Monthly", Value = "Monthly" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Weekly", Value = "Weekly" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Daily", Value = "Daily" }
};

ViewBag.PaymentStructure = Payment;
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentStructure, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentStructure, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PaymentStructure, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentStructure, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Full Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditOrder(int id)
      {
        List<SelectListItem> Payment = new List<SelectListItem>()
          {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Annually", Value = "Annually" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Monthly", Value = "Monthly" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Weekly", Value = "Weekly" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Daily", Value = "Daily" },
         };
        ViewBag.PaymentStructure = Payment;
        var order = db.Orders.Find(id);
        if (order == null)
           {
           return HttpNotFound();
           }
           return View(order);
       }
```

Comment: Try doing this `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new SelectList(your list), "- Please Select -", new {  })`

Comment: I updated my original post - it still does not seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you show your controller where you set the model before getting it to the view?

Comment: OK - See if that helps. I added the full controller code.

Comment: @EbertB did you find a solution for this? Can you share please?

Comment: Yes - Bosco led me to the right solution. My issue was the name of the dropdown needed to be different then the name of my db fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the chat disscussion, These are the steps to take in order to acheive what you want.

**The Controller:**

```
public ActionResult EditOrder(int id)
{
    List<SelectListItem> Payment = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Annually", Value = "Annually" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Monthly", Value = "Monthly" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Weekly", Value = "Weekly" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Daily", Value = "Daily" },
    };
    ViewBag.PaymentStructure = Payment;

    var order = db.Orders.Find(id);
    //NOTE for the dropdown to populate, order.PaymentStructure must have any of this values ("Annually", "Monthly","Weekly","Daily"), debug at this point to confirm the value of order.PaymentStructure
    if (order == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(order);
}
```

**The View:** *No Changes*

```
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentStructure, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentStructure, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PaymentStructure, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentStructure, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the most easiest way to do this is using 'DropDownListFor' as following

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new SelectList(itemslist), "[Select an Item]", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

use `@class = "form-control"` if your using bootstrap or any other Html attribute required