# How to set default value for ASP.NET MVC DropDownList from ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In the controller Index I have the following:

```
ViewBag.Assignees = (await GetAllUsers()).Select(a =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = a.DisplayName,
                Value = a.Username,
                Selected = a.DisplayName == "John Smith"
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

In the View, I have the following:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Assignee, 
                       ViewBag.Assignees as List<SelectListItem>, 
                       "Select Assignee", 
                       new { id = "ddlAssignee", @class = "form-control"})
```

The dropdownlist populates as expected, however, the default (selected = true) value, which does exist, does not get set. Can someone advise what is wrong in the above?

**UPDATE:**

By Changing the `SelectListItem.Value` to `a.DisplayName` (same as `SelectedListItem.Text`) I achieved it. Still not sure what prevents the dropdownlist from displaying the item with `Selected = true`

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312206/edit-view-droplist-select-option-dislaying-the-current-value/57332068#57332068) and see if it helps

Comment: @Bosco your solution populates the dropdownlist and displays the first item on the list. In my scenario, the default value is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If the `model.Assignee` comes with value, and if it is an int it will be defaulted to 0, it will override the *SelectListItem* selected value.

I suggest to set up the `model.Assignee`.

Comment: Adding a new property to my model just to assign a default value does not seem the best approach. I have multiple of these dropdownlists in my page and would to stay away from this as much as I can. Any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here two ways that i use.
WAY 1

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Assignee, 
                      ViewBag.Assignees as List<SelectListItem>, 
                      "Value", // property to be set as Value of dropdown item
                      "Text",  // property to be used as text of dropdown item
                      "1"), // value that should be set selected of dropdown
                      new { id = "ddlAssignee", @class = "form-control"})


WAY 2 

<select name="SelectName" value="1" class="w-100">
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Collection) {
    <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
  }
</select>
```

I hope it work for you

[@Html.DropDownListFor how to set default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value)

Comment: I need to determine the default value in the controller and not the view.

Comment: @amindomeniko do you want to know the selected value??

Comment: Yes, I have a default text "John Smith" in the controller

Comment: @amindomeniko you will receibe it from the property name of the select

Answer (score 0):

In your view set:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Assignee, 
                       ViewBag.Assignees as List<SelectListItem>, 
                       "Select Assignee", 
                       new { id = "ddlAssignee", @class = "form-control", @value = "Default value"})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have list already defined.
Use This

```
@Html.DropDownList("CoverageDropDown", new SelectList(Model.youList, "Code", "Description",item.seletecItem), "Select")
```